# Unable to submit your request Magento Contact Form Error

Tags: email, contact-us

I keep getting this error when trying to submit my contact form:
"Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later"

I'm using default Magento contact form.

Does anyone know where to start with this? It was working a few days ago and now it's not.

I've also been having issues with sales emails sending.

Thanks in advance.

---

In the example below I tried to go to an order and click "send email" then I tired to fill out the contact form on the front end...

```
# root path of bitnami installation replaced with [root]

2013-08-23T11:06:05+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in [root]/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 [root]/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 [root]/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(454): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(506): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#4 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(79): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('sales_email_ord...', 'sales', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#5 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1321): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#6 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(130): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->sendNewOrderEmail()
#7 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->emailAction()
#8 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('email')
#9 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 [root]/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 [root]/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
2013-08-23T11:07:48+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in [root]/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 [root]/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 [root]/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(454): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(506): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send('christinarule@g...', NULL, Array)
#4 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php(104): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('contacts_email_...', 'custom2', 'example@g...', NULL, Array)
#5 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Contacts_IndexController->postAction()
#6 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('post')
#7 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 [root]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 [root]/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 [root]/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

Comment: which error? ^^

Comment: Please share the error and at least the extension you're using for the contact form (default Magento I guess?)

Comment: @Fabian Blechschmidt sorry I forgot to include. The error is  "Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later"

Comment: @Sander Mangel sorry added above. Using default.

Comment: turn on the logging (`system->configuration->developer->log settings`), then try again. You should see your error in `var/log/exception.log` or `var/log/system.log`. If the error message does not help you, post it in the question.

Comment: This error normally means, your server was not able to send an email. The question is why.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Marius his answer, if it's the mail server I suggest contacting the hosting company to set up a mailing server on your server or use [Aschroder's SMTP extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ASchroder/extension/1865/aschroder.com-smtp-pro) to configure a SMTP connection

Comment: we do have that extension installed. Would I also need to contact our hosting company and have them set something else up?

Comment: If you already have this extension running, can you check if the SMTP server you're connecting to is still available? For example by using outlook to send an email via this SMTP server

Comment: @Christina - I was about to suggest this too based on the error log. The bitnmai stack and filepaths makes me think it might be on AWS though? If it's on AWS you might want to look at SES http://aws.amazon.com/ses/ - I've used that before with Ashley Shroder's extension on a Magento site and it works fine.

Comment: @sander-mangel great idea! I did test this an the SMTP is working correctly on my Apple Mail. It is a 'at'bellsouth.net account I don't know if that has anything to do with it? It was working before with the exact email so this is puzzling.

Comment: @McNab We are hosting on an amazon server. Is the service you're talking about an additional fee?

Comment: Just to be sure, try and use a Gmail account as test to see if it's the extension/server or the mail account. Any Gmail account will do, you can find SMTP settings under settings in Gmail

Comment: Christina - Yes it is paid for but it is absolute peanuts and there are other benefits.  http://www.aschroder.com/2011/03/magento-amazon-simple-email-service-ses-added-to-smtp-pro-1-4-3/.  To add to Sander's point about Gmail (sorry Sander, didn't mean to hijack your answer :) ) you can also use Google apps accounts in the Gmail settings, doesn't have to be @gmail.com account

Comment: @SanderMangel does it have to be the same gmail email that is used on the sales emails and other areas of the site?

Comment: I don't think it's required but would likely result in emails ending up in spam. As @Marius pointed out, a Google Apps account would allow you to keep your own email address. But for testing purposes a normal gmail account would do.

Comment: @SanderMangel what if I'm still having the same issues with the google account?

Comment: @SanderMangel I was able to receive an email using the "run self test" in the ASchroder extension on the backend of the site...  However I'm still getting the same error "Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later" on the front end when I try and use the contact form. Sales emails are also not sending..

Comment: It sounds like it's less of an email client issue and more of a coding issue. Do you perhaps have a 3th party extension that overwrites the default email functionality or the templates or listens to an observer tied to emailing? Perhaps try to use the default locale email templates from a backup to send mails out

Comment: @SanderMangel I don't believe I have a 3rd party extension that is overwriting anything, but how could I check for sure?

Comment: @SanderMangel any ideas? would you be interested in investigating for a mini freelance gig? I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem and error message. I also had the excellent SMTP Pro installed.

When I ran the SMTP self test via admin it sent the email successfully but still gave me a red error response. Also it would fail when sending an enquiry via the contact form.

For me, the problem was a conflict with the **Ebizmarts MageMonkey** extension.

According to the aschroder_smtppro.log

```
2014-10-10T00:09:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): Running SMTP Pro Self Test
2014-10-10T00:09:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): Checking config re-writes have not clashed.
2014-10-10T00:09:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): Detected overwrite conflict: Ebizmarts_Mandrill_Model_Email_Template
2014-10-10T00:09:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): Using Google Apps/Gmail Transport.
2014-10-10T00:09:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): Skipping raw connection test for non-SMTP options.
2014-10-10T00:09:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): Actual email sending test...
2014-10-10T00:09:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): Zend_Mail Object
```

As we aren't even using the Mandrill component of MageMonkey, removing the `Ebizmarts_Mandrill.xml` from /app/etc/modules resolved this conflict and now everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. You don't have a mail server configured, or you are not linked correctly.
Or your e-mail template is wrong. If you have changed the e-mail template for the contact form try with the default one. If that works check the differences between the default one and yours.
**[EDIT]**
The exception is thrown if something gors wrong in `Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail::_sendMail()` around these lines:

```
$result = mail(
            $this->recipients,
            $this->_mail->getSubject(),
            $this->body,
            $this->header,
            $this->parameters);
```

IF you say the template file is there then the problem is with the mail server. Try to log the values in the code above, and "manually" test the `mail` function with the values you log and with other test values. This way you can see of the values are wrong or the mail server has a problem.

Comment: thanks so much. It says I am using "default template from local" where can I view this to confirm it's there and in the right order?

Comment: @ChristinaRule. It should be in app/locale/{lang_ISO}/template/email/contact_form.html

Comment: Yup it's there all right....mhhh so this makes me think it's either something with our Amazon server or something with the @bellsouth.net

Comment: @ChristinaRule. I've added some more info on the error. It's not really an answer but should help you debug the issue.

Comment: thanks so much. I just tried a gmail address and that isn't working either. Would it be a mail server issue or is it possible it's something with the actual amazon server? This is so crazy it's taken this long to make a form work! Thanks for all your help @Marius

Comment: now I'm getting email at my gmail account now saying "Suspicious sign in prevented" so now Google is blocking this?